# Xamarin viewcell not update with custom webview inside

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I try to add my customrenderer webview inside a listview, but after some first items renderer correctly, it's appearing with large blank space in the bottom. Even when I go back to some element that already rendered correctly, blank space appeared. 
Here is my code in xaml and customrenderer in android project

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="#f3f3f3" Padding="5,10,5,5">
                                <Frame Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" CornerRadius="15" Padding="15">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <FlexLayout Margin="0,5,0,0" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Frame VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" Padding="0" CornerRadius="100">
                                                    <Frame VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" Padding="0" CornerRadius="100" BackgroundColor="red" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                                        <ffloadingImage:CachedImage HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" Source="{Binding Avatar}" Aspect="Fill"/>
                                                    </Frame>
                                                </Frame>
                                                <FlexLayout Direction="Column" Margin="10,0,0,0" JustifyContent="Start" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="150" AlignItems="Stretch">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName, Converter={converter:ShortenDisplayNameConverter}}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding ActiveTime, Converter={converter:RelativeDateTimeConvertor}}" TextColor="{StaticResource grayColor}" FontSize="11"/>
                                                </FlexLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Frame FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start" Margin="0,0,20,0" Padding="12,3,12,3" 
                                               BackgroundColor="{StaticResource mainColor}" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="50">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Mon}" FontSize="11" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </FlexLayout>
                                        <BoxView Margin="10,0,10,0" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource grayColor}" Opacity=".2"/>
                                        <!--<Label Margin="12,0,12,0" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black"/>-->


                                            <uc:ExtendedWebViewForComment Navigating="OnNavigating" x:Name="webview" HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <uc:ExtendedWebViewForComment.Source>
                                                    <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding Body}"/>
                                                </uc:ExtendedWebViewForComment.Source>
                                            </uc:ExtendedWebViewForComment>
```

And here is the code in android

```
public class ExtendedWebViewForCommentRenderer: WebViewRenderer
{
    WebView _webView;

    public ExtendedWebViewForCommentRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    class ExtendedWebViewForCommentClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        ExtendedWebViewForCommentRenderer _renderer;
        private readonly ExtendedWebViewForComment _xWebView;
        string _lastUrlNotOverridden;

        public ExtendedWebViewForCommentClient(ExtendedWebViewForCommentRenderer renderer, ExtendedWebViewForComment xWebView)
        {
            _renderer = renderer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("renderer");
            _xWebView = xWebView;
        }
        public override async void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            if (_xWebView != null)
            {
                int i = 10;
                while (view.ContentHeight == 0 && i-- > 0) // wait here till content is rendered
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(10);
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200);
                _xWebView.HeightRequest = view.ContentHeight;
                //Console.WriteLine(view.ContentDescription);
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);
                (_xWebView.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as ViewCell).ForceUpdateSize();
                view.Settings.TextZoom = 90;
            }
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

            var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
            var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, url, WebNavigationResult.Success);
            _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            var args = new WebNavigatingEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url }, url);
            _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigating(args);
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            _lastUrlNotOverridden = null;
            if (_renderer?.Element == null || request?.Url == null)
                return true;
            var url = request.Url.ToString();
            if (url == WebViewRenderer.AssetBaseUrl)
                return false;

            var args = new WebNavigatingEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url }, url);
            _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigating(args);
            _lastUrlNotOverridden = args.Cancel ? null : url;

            return args.Cancel;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        _webView = Control;

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewForCommentClient(this, e.NewElement as ExtendedWebViewForComment));
            var nativeWebView = Control;
            nativeWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: May be it has something to do with cache strategy of listview or ForceUpdateSize of viewcell. I tried some but can not fix it

Comment: Have you tried using a CollectionView instead of a ListView?

Comment: I've already try CollectionView but result still the same

Comment: Hmm then it seems like something to do with your custom renderer :/ Have you tried stripping off the non essentials? And does this work on iOS?

Comment: I've not built in Ios yet

Comment: What exactly goes inside this web view ?